# Positioning the added tr within the table

Tags: jquery

I would like to add table row to my table body, which I can achieve with this code:

```
var tr = $('<tr/>');
$('#myTable > tbody:last').append(tr);
```

However some pages could have too many rows and hence I create dynamically a paginator in the last row.

In those cases if I used the code above the new `tr` would be appended below the paginator, which isn't nice.

My paginator `tr` has the id `<tr id="paginator_tr">`  I wonder if I could alter this code

```
$('#myTable > tbody:last').append(tr);
```

with a condition to check if the last tr has the `id = "paginator_tr"` if so, then add the new row before that paginator row. Otherwise simply append the new row as the last row.

Are conditionals like this possible in jquery?

Comment: Next time a fiddle would be appreciated, have you considered using the css :not() pseudoselector?

Comment: I was wondering if it would be easier for you to prepend new tr's to your paginator. You can check if a paginator exists before that. Jquery prepend: http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $tbody = $('#myTable > tbody').last(),
    $paginator_tr = $tbody.find('#paginator_tr');

if ($paginator_tr.length) {
    $paginator_tr.before(tr)
} else {
    $tbody.append(tr)
}
```

You can use `before` method if the paginator element exists otherwise you can append the tr element.

Answer (score 0):

Use `insertBefore()` assuming your pagination row always exists

```
tr.insertBefore( '#paginator_tr')
```

API reference: http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/

Comment: @DavidThomas  as I stated `if row always exists`

Comment: Not before I left the comment you didn't, that was edited-in.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach, which is possibly only slightly insane (though it works!):

```
var table = $(this),
    tr = $('<tr />'),
    td = $('<td />', {'text' : 'Newly-added cell.'}).appendTo(tr),
    method = table.find('#paginator_row').length ? ['insertBefore', '#paginator_row'] : ['appendTo', table.find('tbody').last()]
    tr[method[0]](method[1]);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fPGP9/).

Effectively the `method` array contains two arguments, the first is the jQuery method to use and the second is the selector for that method, to determine where the `tr` element is added; it relies on the fact that an object's properties can be accessed via both dot-notation (`object.propertyName`) and through the use of square brackets (`object[propertyName]`).

References:

- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/).